# What is the location that websites use when Chrome alerts with ".. wants to store files on this device" and where can I change it?

Tags: google-chrome

At the moment there are some websites where in chrome, if I go to them and click to download a file,  I get this screen saying that blah-website 'wants to store files on this device".

I understand that this alert is now something Chrome  does or may do [Website Wants to Store Files on this Device? (Chrome)](https://superuser.com/questions/1190803/website-wants-to-store-files-on-this-device-chrome)

If I click allow then a progress bar appears at the top

But I don't see  where the file is downloading too. I don't see it in the folder set in Chrome as my downloads folder.

Where is it being stored while it downloads, and can I change this location?

If it's a big file I want it stored on an external drive.

[image]

Comment: maybe mentiioned https://superuser.com/questions/507536/where-does-google-chrome-save-localstorage-from-extensions

Answer (score 0):

The popup you are referring too is a result of a website trying to use the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction).

Chrome on windows currently stores these files in `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System` with different folders for each site origin that requested the API.